# If a person has doubts about the oneness of Allah but he doesn't want to have these doubts, will his salah be accepted?

Tags: salat, doubts

Let's say there is a man who is having doubts about the oneness of Allah. In his head, he keeps thinking that god is divisible or prophets can be parts of god. No matter how hard he tries, he just can't seem to get rid of these doubts, because they make some sense to him. But he also knows that in Islam, having these sort of thoughts is shirk. That's why he is scared of having these sort of thoughts.

But the man continues to pray salah, hoping that Allah will eventually make these thoughts go away. He has a hard time concentrating in salah because he can't focus on the oneness of Allah. But he keeps going. He keeps telling himself "Allah is the most merciful. He will accept my salah, even though I have these doubts."

But will Allah even accept his salah?

Comment: What was wrong with the answers here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36745/im-too-scared-to-pray-salah-because-of-my-doubts/36751#36751 ? Were you expecting a more categoric answer? This kind of doubt is not really shirk in the usual sense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Essalamou alikoum,
I think my brother that your source of doubt is coming from a lack of information or non truthful side of Islam and yourself as a human, excuse me for saying that you should read a bit about universe and science more deeply, not just what atheist try to show to people, I am a physicist and I am muslim not because my father was a muslim, but because I believe and I am certain that islam is true. From the point of science, you should not just follow without proof, even yourself. Ourselves have some fantasmic imaginations that we should polish them with our minds. From the point of Islam, the Islam is asking his followers to be reasonable and use scientific approach in their lives, in many chapters in quran God says

''And We have made the night and the day two Signs, and the Sign of night We have made dark, and the Sign of day We have made sightgiving, that you may seek bounty from your Lord, and that you may know the computation of years and the science of reckoning. And everything We have explained with a detailed explanation. ''

'' We created man from an extract of clay.  Then We made him as a drop in a place of settlement, firmly fixed.  Then We made the drop into an alaqah (leech, suspended thing, and blood clot), then We made the alaqah into a mudghah (chewed substance)...''

take these verses of quran and compare them to what the actual science discovered and judge by yourself. Quran is encouraging people to find a wrong information in it, but no way, it is the unique book on earth that starts with ''this book contains no doubt'' . It can be a long discussion, but just focus on being scientific and check facts yourself and do not listen to others to guide your future and In shaa Allah all your doubt will disappear. Salam

Answer (score 0):

Per Islam:

- The Salah of the sincere Muslim is accepted.
- The Salah of the sincere Muslim afflicted with waswasa is accepted.

On the other hand:

- The Salah of the Mushrik/Kafir [disbeliever, firm in disbelief] is not accepted.
- The Salah of the Munafiq [hypocrite, pretends to be Muslim while being a disbeliever; have true doubts] is not accepted.

To me.. the key words of your description is "*they make some sense to him*". If any concepts of Shirk truly "make sense" to you, then you have issues with Aqeedah, my friend. It will nullify your deeds entirely.. because that is what shirk does. The person will have to purify his Aqeedah until he no longer thinks the falsehood/shirk 'makes sense'/is legit.

Truly fearing Allah's (ﷻ) punishment [Hell] would entail giving up that which earns His Wrath. It's for this reason that this person should take steps to do so by self-purification/repentance and seeking knowledge to dispel ignorance/falsehood from the mind plus in the meanwhile, continue praying. This is definitely the correct way to go @ "the man continues to pray salah, hoping that Allah will eventually make these thoughts go away".

Comment: But what if it made sense to me because there is no way to disprove it? How can I convince myself out of it? I don't want it to make sense to me. In fact, I want this thought to be completely gone from my head. But the biggest problem is that I can't disprove it. That's what makes it so scary. What if I prayed salah to make the thought go away? Will Allah accept my salah? I'm a very sincere muslim. Yes, I commit sins every now and then, but I feel very connected to Allah and I love making him happy. I also make dhirk very frequently. It's just my thoughts that I can't control.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is: what if I have a doubt about Islam which I can't falsify? For example, what if a muslim starts thinking "Maybe there is no god. Maybe we're just computer simulations in an alien's computer". How would gaining Islamic knowledge cure this doubt? Because if you think about it, this kind of doubt is unfalsifiable. There's nothing in Islam that can convince you that we're not a bunch of simulations on an alien's computer. So how can anyone possibly get rid of this doubt? And now, he can't pray to Allah to make this doubt go away because Allah will not accept his salah.

Comment: Munafiq and having doubt are different things.  Please clarify that in your answer.

Comment: @Curiosity - Islam has falsified any "what if"/"maybe" questions with the simple statement "Produce your proof, if you should be truthful" (Qur'an). And the Prophet (ﷺ) said, 'burden of proof is on the claimant". -- So it doesn't matter what claim you make under the Sun.. you need to give evidence first. Islam actually came with evidences, logic, etc.

Comment: @Kilise - They are not exclusive. 'Doubt' is the key characteristic of hypocrites.

Comment: Give me a reference of that definition. You can doubt without being a hypocrite. Every hypocrite aren't doubters either.

Comment: Allah (ﷻ) said of Munafiqeen specifically that they have a 'disease' of doubt in various places such as 2:10, 9:45. -- Moreover, you said, “doubt without being a hypocrite” -  True doubt is Kufr either way.. something Muslims don’t have [Qur’an 49:15]. BUT, to not fall into the category of a hypocrite would mean you’re not claiming to be Muslim.. which hypocrites do which is why I made them a separate category.. if that makes sense.

Comment: First of all 2:10 addresses (inna alladhina kafaroo). 63:1-8 describes almonafiqeen. Having doubt is not always kufr.

Comment: "Having doubt is not always kufr" - Confusion/doubts coming across your mind is not Kufr but settling on doubt is indeed Kufr.. because a Muslim cannot have doubts about Allah or His religion. Please refer to the verse I quoted again. -- Never has Islam said it's OK to have doubts.. so I'm not sure why you're arguing. Show a verse that says otherwise, if you believe so.

Comment: 49:14  is a verse pointing on the 3rab saying we believe. Whilst its said to them Say we have submit because yet has not true belief entered your hearts. It didn't say "qol kafarna... it said qol aslamna"

Comment: Yes, it didn't say qol kafarna because the verse didn't attribute 'doubt' to either those who submit [Muslims] and those who Believe [Mumimeen]. It only points out that the latter is higher status than the former... due to combination of qualities/actions Allah (ﷻ) mentioned.

Comment: Anyway, I clarified what a hypocrite is in the answer.. lest it confuse others. Peace.